# MySQL - Add number of days to date in 3rd column automatically

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

I have a table with two columns.

The first column has a list of dates and the second column has a list of days.

```
2018/01/01 - 20
```

I would like the two columns to calculate to add 20 days to the date to get 2018/01/21 and put into a 3rd column. How can this be done so every time the table is updated with a new row it automatically adds the two together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 5.7.something +, you can create a generated column:

```
alter table t add (col1 + interval col2 day);
```

In earlier versions you can use a view:

```
create view v_t as
    select t.*, (col1 + interval col2 day) as col3
    from t;
```