# Automatically add days to a column based on other table columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table A which has column NoOfDays, and another table B which has a column MyDate of type datetime and it is set to Default as "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP".
Now in table B, I want to add a new column (called ValidDate), which should AUTOMATICALLY store the sum value of (B.MyDate + A.NoOfDays)

For example, if B.MyDate has value of "`2022-07-25 04:50:26`" and A.NoOfDays has value of "`60`", then B.ValidDate should get the value of "`2022-09-23 04:50:26`"

What is the way in MySQL to set this new column value to store this summed value automatically.

Checked for existing threads, but found only this one which does not offer a solution to store, but to create a view output only.
[MySQL - Add number of days to date in 3rd column automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48958850/mysql-add-number-of-days-to-date-in-3rd-column-automatically)

Comment: You most likely have to use triggers, see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by automatically, triggers only respond to events , do you mean on insert or update set the column value? If not then what? NB why store something you can easily calculate anyway?

Comment: @P.Salmon - Your q is valid. Literal "Automatically" word would imply happening on its own, and Trigger will be the right fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For existing rows in table_b , use an update statement like `UPDATE table_b set ValidDate=date_add(MyDate , interval + (select NoOfDays from table_a) day);` 
For new inserts, we can use a trigger to handle that. Here is the complete script written and tested in workbench:

```
create table table_a (NoOfDays int);
create table table_b(MyDate timestamp,ValidDate datetime); 
insert table_a values(60);
DELIMITER //
drop trigger if exists  auto_sum //
create trigger auto_sum before insert on table_b for each row begin
set new.ValidDate=date_add(new.MyDate , interval + (select NoOfDays from table_a) day);
end // 
delimiter ;
insert into table_b (MyDate) values (default); -- The value of ValidDate is calculated in the trigger,so we only need to specify the value for MyDate.
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (NoOfDays INT);
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES(60);
CREATE TABLE TableB(MyDate DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES('2022-07-25 04:50:26');
ALTER TABLE TableB
ADD ValidDate DATETIME;
UPDATE TableB
SET ValidDate = date_add(MyDate, INTERVAL (SELECT NoOfDays FROM TableA) DAY);
```

If we test the result :

```
SELECT * FROM TableB;
```

[image: Click to see image]

Comment: Thanks @OzanSen. Your answer is right, but my need is more to get this done automatically on each insert. The other answer (with Trigger) makes the right fit. Plus one to you too. Thanks.

Comment: @levent001 It is you who will decide which one suits best for your needs. If your problem is solved, then I am pleased. Stay safe, be well. :)